# Risk in switching from Salesforce Platform user License to Salesforce user license

Tags: licenses, permission-sets

I want to know what are the risks in switching from Salesforce Platform user License to Salesforce user license. For a particular profile of users i need to give them assign permission set & manage profile and permission sets administrative permissions. But seems like it is not possible with Salesforce Platform Profile and assigning a separate permission set with these 2 permissions. Please suggest.

Answer (score 1):

**Salesforce** licenses are designed for users who require full access to standard CRM and Force.com AppExchange apps. CRM apps are anything that requires access to Standard Objects like...

- Leads
- Opportunities
- Forecasts
- Cases
- Solutions

Apart from that Salesforce License comes with following functionality

- Ability to manage internal users
- Authoring Apex
- Managing Package licences
- Managing sharing
- Managing login access policy

**Salesforce Platform** licenses are designed for users who only need access to custom apps, and NOT the standard CRM functionality. Salesforce Platform users DO have access to the "core" Salesforce Standard Objects and functionality, like...

- Accounts
- Contacts
- Reports
- Dashboards
- Documents
- Custom Tabs

So when you change your license type you are extending Salesforce functionality instead of user rights. User accessibility to those feature can be governed by **Profile** or **Permission set**